# How to add VueJS's v-model attribute into Symfony2 form type

Tags: forms, symfony, attributes, vue.js

I think form types is good enough to create form easily and I use VueJS on part of my project's form. **(Symfony 2.8)** My issue is that I am not able to add "v-model" attribute to any input as custom attribute.

```
$builder
    ->add('pcs', TextType::class, [
        'label' => "Adet",
        'attr' => [
            'class' => "form-control",
            'v-model' => "pcs"
        ]
    ]);
```

When I run the code, it removes the "v-model" attribute from the input.

```
<input type="text" id="product_pcs" name="product[pcs]" required="required" class="form-control">
```

I tried custom form template and I could not do that. Attributes templates are so complex. If you have any info about that issue or templates, I'll be greateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal this issue is to make Symfony indifferent of the library that you use in the frontend. You can modify the field's attributes directly in the Twig template, like this:

`{{ form_widget(form.pcs, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'v-model': 'pcs'}}) }}`

Comment: This is what I thought too, but I'm getting a `v-model` warning that the `value` tag can't be included? The only way around that (since it's auto-generated by the Form component) is to make it a hidden field and copy it on page load. Is that what you would do?

Comment: The error I receive: *inline value attributes will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.*